# MySQL statement returns true but doesn't insert

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following

```
$bd = new mysqli("localhost","root","","bd");

$title = $_POST['title'];
$text = $_POST['content'];
$id = intval($_SESSION['id']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO `perguntas` (per_number, per_title, per_text, per_usr_id) VALUES (1, ?, ?, ?)";
$query = $bd->prepare($sql);
if ($query) {
    $query->bind_param("ssi", $title, $text, $id);
    $query->execute();
    $query->close();
}
else {
    die("Something went wrong");
}
$bd->close();
```

Basically `$query` returns true but doesn't insert into database. I've tried to use queries instead of statements and I get the same problem. Not sure what's causing it either.
I've confirmed all variables and they contain text, I just omitted `isset()`.
I even tried using this query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `perguntas` (per_number, per_title, per_text, per_usr_id) VALUES (1, 'Test', 'test', 1)";
```

All table datatypes are correct. `per_number` is int, `per_title` is varchat, `per_text` is text and `per_usr_id` is int.

[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veZgg.png)

Comment: Different database?

Comment: instead of looking up the prepare return, lookup the success of $query->execute();

Comment: Nop, correct database. Also it reserves the id (table "perguntas" as an auto increment id).

Comment: @xymenez please check if session is started :D

Comment: I forgot to paste it here. Session is started and it's returning values properly. Code is now working. I guess it has something to do with me not closing the statments and connection and all those tries were pending.

Answer (score 0):

1) I think You've forgot to start session: `session_start()`  since I see You're trying to get `$_SESSION['id']` that cannot be retrieved without starting it.

2) Maybe title or content may be empty string too. 
So make sure You're passing values from form correctly.

Check Your issue after running `execute` method.

Check this code:

```
<?php
session_start(); 

$db = new mysqli("localhost","root","","bd");

$title = trim($_POST['title']);
$text = trim($_POST['content']);
$id = $_SESSION['id'];

if (!$title) throw new Exception('Incorrect or empty title');
if (!$text) throw new Exception('Incorrect or empty text');
if (!is_numeric($id)) throw new Exception('Non numeric id');

$query = 'INSERT INTO `perguntas` 
          (per_number, per_title, per_text, per_usr_id) 
          VALUES 
          (1, ?, ?, ?)';
$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->bind_param("ssi", $title, $text, $id);

if (!$statement->execute()) throw new Exception($statement->error);

$statement->close();
$db->close();
```

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the table. No unique indexes. Also I tried to edit one field in a row and all the pending rows suddenly appeared. What?!

Comment: Just try to run the code from my answer to see what's missing

Comment: When I created the script, I forgot about the closes and I guess all those tries were in stand by. Now it's working as intended before I had the chance to try yours.